# How to avoid this 1.0E+12 number format in VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have an `Estimated Value` field on the `Account` object. I am using that field on a `Visualforce Page` to search.

When user enters more than 9 values (eg: `10000000000`) and clicks on the search button it converts formats the number like `1.0E+12`.

How can I avoid this and make store the unformulated value (`10000000000`)?

Markup:

```
<apex:input type="number" value="{!estimatedValue}"/>
```

Apex:

```
public Double estimatedValue { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if I bind to a `Double` I observe the behavior you described, whereas with a basically any other number `Type` I do not.

```
public Double doubleValue { get; set; }   // displays as you observe
public Decimal decimalValue { get; set; } // displays as you want
public Integer integerValue { get; set; } // displays as you want
public Long longValue { get; set; }       // displays as you want
```